# Elementree XML to dataframe in multiple sheet with attributes extraction

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

Consider a XML like below having multiple classes like `NRREL`,`NRRELE` and many more,I have only two here for example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE raml SYSTEM 'raml20.dtd'>
<raml version="2.0" xmlns="raml20.xsd">
  <cmData type="actual">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2023-12-20T16:11:15.000+05:30" action="created" appInfo="ActualExporter">InternalValues are used</log>
    </header>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-1" id="14823863">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277215</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">16</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-131" id="14823714">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277240</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">18</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">0</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRREL" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-0/NRREL-132" id="14823717">
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset">24</p>
      <p name="cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset">24</p>
      <p name="gNbId">277227</p>
      <p name="gNbIdLength">22</p>
      <list name="gnbPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSA">1</p>
      <p name="handoverAllowedSARedCap">0</p>
      <p name="isRplCellForPSCell">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">18</p>
      <p name="nrDcAllowed">0</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">0</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRRELE" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-2/NRRELE-95" id="14823887">
      <p name="cellIndividualOffset">24</p>
      <p name="eNodeBId">7948</p>
      <list name="ecgiPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="eutranCellBlacklisted">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">16</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="NRRELE" version="NRBTSCL23R4_2315_120" distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-277215/NRBTS-277215/NRCELL-2/NRRELE-96" id="14823888">
      <p name="cellIndividualOffset">24</p>
      <p name="eNodeBId">32</p>
      <list name="ecgiPlmn">
        <item>
          <p name="mcc">405</p>
          <p name="mnc">854</p>
          <p name="mncLength">3</p>
        </item>
      </list>
      <p name="eutranCellBlacklisted">0</p>
      <p name="lcrId">50</p>
      <p name="removeNotAllowed">1</p>
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

I Need an output in `dataframe` which can create a seperate data frame as per Class (NRRELE,NRREL...and more) which I can possible export in excel sort of like below

**NRREL dataframe**

```html
       MRBTS           NRBTS           NRCELL          NRREL           id          cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset         cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset         gNbId           gNbIdLength         gnbPlmn         Item-gnbPlmn-mcc        Item-gnbPlmn-mnc        Item-gnbPlmn-mncLength          handoverAllowedSA           handoverAllowedSARedCap         isRplCellForPSCell          lcrId           nrDcAllowed         removeNotAllowed
277215  277215  0   1   14823863    24  24  277215  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   16  0   1
277215  277215  0   131 14823714    24  24  277240  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   18  0   0
277215  277215  0   132 14823717    24  24  277227  22  List    405 854 3   1   0   0   18  0   0
```

**NRRELE dataframe**

```html
       MRBTS           NRBTS           NRCELL          NRRELE          id          cellIndividualOffset        eNodeBId        ecgiPlmn        Item-ecgiPlmn-mcc           Item-ecgiPlmn-mnc           Item-ecgiPlmn-mncLength         eutranCellBlacklisted           lcrId           removeNotAllowed
277215  277215  2   95  14823887    24  7948    List    405 854 3   0   16  1
277215  277215  2   96  14823888    24  32  List    405 854 3   0   50  1
```

Comment: Please show us, what you have tried so far and what is your problem or question. This is not a code generator platform for you.

Comment: Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for a Python implementation to build data frame(s) from XML and make an earnest effort at solution. Then, ask about your *specific* attempt not an open-ended, free coding service request. Many such questions have been asked and answered on StackOverflow. Happy searching and happy coding!

Comment: Problem iim used to working with dataframes, this was the first time i have encountered and XML of this type with nested children and having attributes within sub elements no matter what i did i was not able traverse into the element ....apologies...i tried a hail mary....

Answer (score 1):

I would use [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup)/[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) for that :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd; import re

with open("file.xml") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), "xml")

out = {}
for mo in soup.select("managedObject"):
    tmp = dict(
        re.findall(r"([^/]+?)-([^/]+)", mo["distName"])[1:], id=mo["id"],
        **{t["name"]: t.get_text() for t in mo.select("p")},
        **{(t:=mo.select(":not(p)")[0])["name"]: t.name}
    )
 
    out.setdefault(mo["class"], []).append(tmp)
```

And below, is a variant/equivalent using [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("file.xml")

out = {}
for mo in root.findall(".//{*}managedObject"):
    tmp = dict(
        re.findall(r"([^/]+?)-([^/]+)", mo.attrib["distName"])[1:],
        id=mo.attrib["id"],
        **{ele.attrib["name"]: ele.text if ((tn:=ele.tag.split("}")[-1]) == "p")
           else tn for ele in mo.findall(".//") if ele.attrib.get("name")},
    )
    
    out.setdefault(mo.attrib["class"], []).append(tmp)
```

To make the Excel spreadsheet, you can use :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("output.xlsx") as writer:
    for k,v in out.items():
        (pd.DataFrame(v).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
             .to_excel(writer, sheet_name=k, index=False))
```

And if you're interested in the intermediate dataframes, you can use :

```
dfs = {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k,v in out.items()}

# to access one of the dataframes, use dict-indexing (e.g `dfs["NRREL"]`)
```

Output (*of dfs*):

```
    MRBTS   NRBTS  NRCELL  ...  lcrId  nrDcAllowed  removeNotAllowed
0  277215  277215       0  ...     16            0                 1
1  277215  277215       0  ...     18            0                 0
2  277215  277215       0  ...     18            0                 0

[3 rows x 19 columns]

    MRBTS   NRBTS  NRCELL  ...  eutranCellBlacklisted  lcrId  removeNotAllowed
0  277215  277215       2  ...                      0     16                 1
1  277215  277215       2  ...                      0     50                 1

[2 rows x 14 columns]
```

Preview (*of output.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: The problem is i tries with beautiful soup and some how the office laptop is not allowing me install that dictionary,i have to make do with elementree ONLY possible with that perhaps ?

Comment: Got you, I just added a variant using [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to the answer.

Comment: BANG!!! Thanks a million bro...u rocked it!!

Comment: OK So there is problem....i am trying to Parse the original document but now what's happening is that i have been sitting for 1 hr approx and the damn thing is still going....after checking my memory usage im seeing its using 99% of the memory while trying to extract the damn thing...my original XML is 33,76,743 KB in size....is there a way to not use any other libraray except ELEMENTREE and get the memory usage down perhaps ?...ALSO i tried with Beautifulsoup on my personal PC it ended giving a memory error

Answer (score -2):

You can use Powershell.  Powershell with Format-Table only displays some columns  although all the data is in the object

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$xmlFilename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$csvFilename = 'c:\temp\test.csv'

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($xmlFilename)
$ns = $xDoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace()

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

foreach($managedObject in $xDoc.Descendants($ns + 'managedObject'))
{
   $class = $managedObject.Attribute('class').Value
   $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
      Class = $class
   }

   $distName = $managedObject.Attribute('distName').Value
   $distNameArray = $distName.Split('/') | foreach { $obj = $_.Split('-'); $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $obj[0] -NotePropertyValue $obj[1] }
   
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName id -NotePropertyValue $managedObject.Attribute('id').Value

   $managedObject.Descendants($ns + 'p') | foreach { $name = $_.Attribute('name').Value; $value = $_.Value; $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $name -NotePropertyValue $value }

   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table
$table | Export-CSV -Path $csvFilename -NoTypeInformation

$classes = $table | Group-Object -Property Class

$classes | foreach { $_.Group | Format-Table }
```

Here are the displayed columns

```
Class PLMN MRBTS  NRBTS  NRCELL NRREL id       cellIndividualSsbRsrpOffset cellIndividualSsbRsrqOffset gNbId
----- ---- -----  -----  ------ ----- --       --------------------------- --------------------------- -----
NRREL PLMN 277215 277215 0      1     14823863 24                          24                          277215
NRREL PLMN 277215 277215 0      131   14823714 24                          24                          277240
NRREL PLMN 277215 277215 0      132   14823717 24                          24                          277227



Class  PLMN MRBTS  NRBTS  NRCELL NRRELE id       cellIndividualOffset eNodeBId mcc
-----  ---- -----  -----  ------ ------ --       -------------------- -------- ---
NRRELE PLMN 277215 277215 2      95     14823887 24                   7948     405
NRRELE PLMN 277215 277215 2      96     14823888 24                   32       405
```

Comment: Suggesting to use PowerShell for a Python question seems a bit counterintuitive.

Comment: @AKX : Alternate solutions are allowed at this website.